# Retrieving access token from Google Signin button

Tags: android, google-app-engine, oauth-2.0

I'm developing an Android application that uses the *Google Signin* button to authenticate. I can sign in and access the user's profile data, but I would like to know the access token.

Can I retrieve it? Do I need to use `GoogleAuthUtil`?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the same doubt, take a look in the PhotoHunt sample... it helped me to solve my problem:
https://developers.google.com/+/photohunt/android